# NRF5 SDK 17.1.0 Threading Model

Tags: multithreading, embedded, nrf52, nrf5-sdk, nordic-semi

Ok, so stupid-newby question-time. Is the default thread model in nRF5 SDK 17.1.0 single threaded with exceptions, interrupts, events, running as ISRs in privileged (i.e. higher priority) stack space?

Is that specific enough, or am I being too general?

BTW, I've tried reading the nrf5 sdk documents. I'm just not finding the answer. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

It is an ARM Cortex-M0 core - there is no separate interrupt/exception stack. [Privilege levels](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0662/b/The-Cortex-M0--Processor/Programmers-model/Processor-modes-and-privilege-levels-for-software-execution) are independent of interrupt/thread context and *optional*.

Looking at the [documentation](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fstruct_sdk%2Fstruct%2Fsdk_nrf5_latest.html&cp=9_1), it appears to be a library to support the hardware rather then an application framework, and therefore has no particular thread model.  As such nothing prevents you from using it with an RTOS of your choice.  There is even a section in the documentation covering that ([Libraries->RTOS support](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fsdk_nrf5_v17.1.0%2Flib_rtos.html&cp=9_1_3_40)).

Comment: Thanks @Clifford. I need to stop being lazy and read the documentation. Appreciate you sharing your knowledge.